# String maipulation for different date format in PHP

Tags: php

I have this

`04/09/2014`

string coming  from a php variable $date how I want it to change to

`04 Sep 2014`

Any idea how can I do this . One way I thought was to

```
 $date1 = explode ("/",$date);
```

and then

```
 match $date1[1] == "string containing the month name "
```

Any other solution which is more easier or better ??

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP's DateTime API (from PHP 5) :

```
//input date format
$in='04/09/2014';
$date=\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $in);
$out=$date->format('d M Y');
//prints 04 Sep 2014
echo $out;
```

See php docs : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php

Comment: the problem I ma facing is its converting the date into months like for 04/09/2014 its printing 09 April 2014 it is suppose to be 04 Sep 2014

Comment: The format is the same for date().
d M Y = 04 Sept 2014
Make sure your M is uppercase:

Comment: got it bro some problem was with my browser refreshed it twice and I saw the new date format thanks :)

Comment: is it possible to generate the month shorthand in spanish ? :)

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
   $originalDate = "04/09/2014";
   $originalDate =date("d/m/Y", strtotime($originalDate));
   $newDate = date("d M Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Comment: Thanks yes it works :) . I will accept the answer after 9 minutes

Comment: @Vikram..Glad to help you :)

Comment: there is a small problem when I use it . It is changing the dtate into month like for 04/09/2014 it is printing 09 april 2014. Its suppose to be 04 Sep 2014

Comment: How you are getting `$date`?

Comment: the $date variable has the string 04/09/2014 I am getting from an array. btw I tried the solution provideed by mat_bs and it worked

Comment: yah..that was because of the format with your string. I have updated my answer. That will work fine.

Comment: thanks but as that time mat_bs solution worked I accepted his answer hope you dont mind :).

Comment: @Vikram..no problem :)

Comment: one last question :) if  you dont mind. The code generates the shorthand in english . If there a way i can change it to spanish because the website I am working for is in spanish